# memory low error after caling database class method

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have bellow class in my project that can help me to run SQL commands directly. in my computer it works fine. but when I published to web server after about 5 or 6 times that I called in page I got memory low error. that error cleaned after about 20 minutes. but it happens again and again.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Globalization;

public class FirstClass
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    DataTable dt;
    SqlDataAdapter da;

    public FirstClass()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebSiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    }

    public DataTable dbSelect(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dttt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return dttt;
        }

    }

    public void exeSp(string spName)
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = spName;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }

    public void exeSqlCmd(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        }
        catch { }

    }
}
```

This mostly happens when I use the first method. Of course, the number of records that are fetched is also important. The higher the number of records fetched, the faster the memory shortage error occurs. But after about 20 minutes, all the bugs will be fixed automatically and I can run the code again. But unfortunately I get the same error message again. Please help.

Comment: How many rows are returned?

Comment: Your usage of `DataTable dt;` is very weird. I would suggest that should not be a field.

Comment: The 20 minutes 'fixed automatically" is probably caused by IIS recycling the appdomain,

Comment: The code shown is just the fetch code. There's a few problems in it re disposal/lifetime, but *the code shown* won't by itself impact memory much. What is more relevant is: how much data are you fetching, and how long are you holding onto it? BTW, the code screams "SQL injection" (no parameters), and both data-adapters and data-tables should usually be avoided except for some niche scenarios; these days, a simple `List<T>` (for some POCO `T`) is usually preferred, usually driven by something like EF or Dapper. I'd also worry about concurrency if this object is shared. Not great code, honestly.

Comment: thanks for your attention. it returns about 7000 to 20000  rows per time. @mjwills

Comment: In a company at UK. @mjwills and my host is windows host and my administration software is PLESK and my database is SQL Server.

Comment: @Meysam One of two things is true. Either a) Your web server is massively underspecced. and / or b) The issue is in code that we can't see. We will need a [mcve] **and the exact error message**.

Comment: My error: There is not enough memory to complete this operation.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: There is not enough memory to
complete this operation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
where it originated in the code. @mjwills

Comment: Just to start with. There is no reason to use a class to hold on to various objects, like SqlConnection. These are lightweight, and should be created for each query, or group of queries done at the same time. With few exceptions they are resources that need to be managed, so use `using` wherever appropriate, for anything that is an IDisposable. The whole thing will usually be within a single method. When all of this is fixed, if you still have problems, then we can reason about them.

Comment: @meysam the error message is about OleDb - but the code you've shown is SqlClient; are you using OleDb somewhere else in the app? If so, for what, and is the problem actually there? Also: how *frequently* are you fetching those 7000-20000 rows? (And *why* are you fetching them? Usually, you should try to leave the data in the database - you should only really need to fetch the rows you're planning to immediately display, which should usually be no more than about 50 rows)

Comment: Yes. when I want to upload excel file to database I used Oledb @Marc Gravell

Comment: OK, so show us _that code_.

Comment: thanks to all @mjwills it works fine. and I used dispose in my excel upload method too. now it works fine without any error. thanks to all.

Comment: If the SQL Server is on the same machine, have you set `max server memory` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question has several issues. I will only explicitly mention some issues related to use of classes in System.Data.SqlClient, and not mention general issues, though the code shown here solves many of the general issues, but not all.

The classes SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter, SqlDataReader and so on, are lightweight, and should be created and released in the innermost scope possible. There is nothing to gain by trying to reuse these by holding on to them across queries. They also need to be properly managed with regards to memory use as well as resource use, not only when execution follows the success path, but also when errors arise. This can be achieved as follows.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public static class FirstClass
{
    private static string connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebSiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public static DataTable DbSelect(string sql)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DataTable result = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(result);
                        return result;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ExeSp(string spName)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = spName;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ExeSqlCmd(string sql)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class has been made static, which makes sure all memory and resource management now takes place within each single method. We no longer rely on knowing how the class itself is used elsewhere in order to understand how things work. Within the methods, use of `using` now clearly tells us how resources, including memory, is allocated and deallocated. We can see that everything is properly disposed, so that there is no longer any way that any resource can be lying around between database calls, whether there's success or error in calls. In the DbSelect method, the `DataTable` is created as close to its point of use as possible, so that we easily see what it's doing.

It is not clear what the intention of having one local and one class level DataTable was in the original code, which returns one or the other - likely just a temporary glitch while experimenting - but in this new version the caller is responsible for disposing the returned result after use. An alternative is possibly to have the caller offer a DataTable to fill in, if that's easier for the caller. If so, just clear the table before filling.

When it comes to error handling, it can be improved, but I won't go into that.

This code compiles, but I have not verified that it actually works. My intention is to show how to organize these kinds of database calls in general, and you can work on fixing any error I may have overlooked from there on.